# Geometric forms of Line and Flux Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I want to prove that

$\int_C \vec v\cdot d \vec r$ =$\int_C \vec v\cdot \vec t ds$

$\int_C \vec v\cdot \vec N(t) ds$ =$\int_C \vec v\cdot \vec n ds$

where $\vec n$ is the unit normal to C, $\vec t$ is the unit tangent to C, C is a regular curve and s is the arclength parameter of C

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_C \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{R} = \int_C \vec{v} \cdot \vec{T} ds
$$
A position vector $\vec{R}(t)=x(t)i+y(t)j$ traces out a curve in 2D space. If you take $$\frac{d\vec{R}}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}i+\frac{dy}{dt}j$$
you get the tangent vector. The unit tangent vector is just the derivative of $R$ divided by its length (sometimes denoted $\frac{d\vec{R}}{ds}$).

The length of the position vector is equal to the step along the curve:
$$
ds=\left|\frac{d\vec{R}}{dt}\right| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}
$$

Therefore:
$$
\int_C \vec{v}\cdot \vec{T}ds = \int_C \vec{v} \cdot \left(\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}i+\frac{dy}{dt}j}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}}\right)\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt = \int_C \vec{v} \cdot \left(\frac{dx}{dt}i+\frac{dy}{dt}j\right)dt \\ = \int_C \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{R}
$$

---

The second equation:
$$
\int_C \vec{v}\cdot \vec{N}ds=\int_C v\cdot \vec{n} ds 
$$
is incorrect. The step on the right hand side should be $dt$.
$$
\int_C \vec{v}\cdot \vec{N}ds = \int_C \vec{v}\cdot \vec{n} dt
$$
This is equation true because the length of the normal vector is the same as the length of the unit tangent vector, and thus the same as $ds$. This is true because for a vector $\vec{v}=xi+yj$, a vector normal to this is $\vec{v}=-yi+xj$ (or $\vec{v}=yi-xj$).

Same as in the previous equation, $ds$ and the length of $\vec{N}$ in the denominator cancel out.